# Why is does the generic <R> go before the return type?

Tags: java

I had to write this function that takes the functional interface `mapper` and maps the elements of a stack to type `<R>`. My question is why the extra generic  before the return type `Stack<R>` is necessary in the map function?

```java
public <R> Stack<R> map(Function<E, R> mapper) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class can be generic or not, but whatever your class is `public class MyClass` or `public class MyClass<E>` it might happen that you would like to offer a method that uses a generic parameter for itself only, that no other methods in your class are using.

So the `<R>` here :

```java
public <R> Stack<R> map(Function<E, R> mapper) {

}
```

means : know that there is a specific parameter I will use here, but for that method only.
it could be specified the same way you would do in a class declaration :

```java
public <R extends Serializable> Stack<R> map(Function<E, R> mapper) {

}
```

for example.

---

In your case, this parameter is used to link the type you return to the type you give in input of this method : it ensures that if you give a mapper of type *Function<E, **R**>*, you will receive an **R** object in return.

---

Another convenient use of these "extra" generic parameters on methods is the dynamic checking of the type of an object returned. I use it often :

```java
public <T> T myMethod(Class<T> expectedClass, int a, int b) {
...
   // My result comes in an object o.
   Object o;

   if (expectedClass.isInstance(o) == false) {
     // ClassCastException
   }

   return (T)o; // You are sure it has the expected type.
}
```

Comment: Can I add multiple "<R>"s, before the return type declaration or just one?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you deal with generics in Java, you have to explicitly tell the method (and the compiler) that you are dealing with that.
How to tell them is this way, adding the `<T>` to the method signature.

Quoting from the link below:

> The  in the method signature implies that the method will be dealing with generic type T. This is needed even if the method is returning void

This is a very shallow explanation but you can read more about [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first `<R>` describes the type that you can use in the method signature, so it adds a placeholder you can use (its a list of usable types anyway). In the `Stack<R>` or `Function<E,R>` the type parameter indicates, that the given generic type must be used from the declared types.

Sometimes it seems unnecessary, but suppose you want to add some bounds to your type.

```
public  <T extends SomeObject & Comparable> Stack<T> map(T x)
```

It will be ugly to write down the whole expression to every places where you want to use them.
Also if you use it for example as an array, you can't do it there:

```
public  <T extends SomeObject & Comparable> Stack<T> map(T[] x)
```

So the first one is the declaration of a type as a placeholder. And the others is the use side of the variance. Then the compiler can check that everything is ok at call sites before type erasure happend.

Answer (score 0):

It call the 'Generic Method'.The `<R>` means the type of the parameter of the method and it will be certain only when method invocation.